# The following sections have been defined but have not been rendered for the layout page even though I have set required:false

Tags: asp.net-mvc

This question has been asked a lot and the answer has always been to set it to `@RenderSection("MySection", false)`

However in my case that is not working.

The error is:

> The following sections have been defined but have not been rendered
>   for the layout page "~/Views/Shared/KittenLayout.cshtml": "styles".

My pages are:

- Kitten.cshtml which has Layout = "~/Views/Shared/KittenLayout.cshtml";
- KittenLayout.cshtml which has two sections defined, `@section stuff` and `section @otherstuff`, and it has Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_KittenMasterLayout.cshtml";
- _KittenMasterLayout.cshtml which has `@RenderSection("styles", required: false)`

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have fixed this, apparently there is no inheritance, so if you have pages A->B->C where A is the main page, B is a master page, and C is a master-master-page, then if you define a section on C and render it on A you'll get an error. You have to add it to B also and just pass it through.

Adding this to page B fixed it:

```
@section styles
{
    @RenderSection("styles", required: false)
}
```